# Sencha Touch: Passing data from the onItemDisclosure to the detail view panel and template

Tags: sencha-touch

I have the usual data passed into my **onItemDisclosure** as below:

```
  onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
       console.log(record.data);
  }...
```

I can see the data no problems but I would like to pass this data onto my panel so its template can then use it?

How would I go about this.

I have this so far in the detailed panel, but with in the panel code how do I then grab this?

```
detailPanel.update(record.data);
```

**UPDATE**

Well having a play around it seems that I placed the data variable within the template as normal and the whole thing works

```
    <tpl for="."><div>{name}</div></tpl>
```

But my Other question is that I have my json set up with a field as below:

```
  "name"," joe bloggs",
   "contacts": [
            {
                "home":"0844 482 5171",
                "mobile":"",
                "work":"0844 482 5100"          
            }],.....
```

Now I can access these if I `console.log(contacts[0].mobile)` but if I place this in the template `<tpl for="."><div>{contacts[0].mobile}</div></tpl>` it just simply prints out `{contacts[0].mobile}`

So how can I obtain this data within contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

use `<tpl for="contacts">{mobile}</tpl>`

**end**

Add the `tpl` property to the `detailPanel` object, like this:

```
tpl:'<h1>{text}</h1>'
```

where `text` is some property of the `record.data` object.

Here are some good tutorials about sencha's templates:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/xtemplates-part-i/

http://www.sencha.com/learn/xtemplates-part-ii/

Comment: Thanks for the reply i just did the '<tpl for="contacts"><div>{mobile}</div></tpl>'... but cannot answer my own question for 8 hours :-) but thanks for this